# Como separar datos de un Dataframe Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

antes que nada aclarar que estoy aprendiendo.
Estoy trabado con el siguiente problema.
Tengo que separar los caracteres de una columna en un DataFrame.
Ya busque por todos lados, no doy con una respuesta que me ayude.

```
df2= pd.read_excel("Ingreso.xlsx")
print(df2)
```

Obtengo

| ID | NUMERO |
| --- | --- |
| 420 | 3783447908 |
| 421 | 3722427446 |
| 426 | 3783444106 |
| 430 | 344240240 |
| 431 | 34427067 |
| 474 | 34654222230 |
| 477 | 3722425691 |
| 478 | 1140656815 |
| 8 | 482 3752427590 |

Yo necesito poder separar en otra Columna los ultimos 7 numeros de cada String de la Columna NUMERO y ponerlo en una nueva columna.

Gracias!

Comment: Es importante que agregues lo que has intentado hasta el momento

Comment: intente con slice y con slip, pero no logre nada, ni siquiera encaminarlo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las Series están equipados con un conjunto de métodos de [procesamiento de cadenas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html) que facilitan la operación en cada elemento de la matriz, y se accede a dichos métodos con el atributo `str`

Así puedes crear tu nueva columna en base a los elementos de la columna `NUMERO`:

`df["LAST 7"] = df["NUMERO"].str[-7:]`

Y el resultado seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### Update 1:

Te dejo por acá el código completo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["ID"] = [420, 421, 426, 430, 431, 474, 477, 478, 482]
df["NUMERO"] = [
    3783447908,
    3722427446,
    3783444106,
    344240240,
    34427067,
    34654222230,
    3722425691,
    11406568158,
    3752427590,
]
df["NUMERO"] = df["NUMERO"].astype(str)
df["LAST 7"] = df["NUMERO"].str[-7:]
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!!

Comment: lo probe y me arroja lo sig. AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?        probe con STD pero tampoco...

Comment: TOmando en cuenta este enunciado **7 numeros de cada String de la Columna NUMERO** se asume que esa columna almacena valores de tipo STR pero por el error no es asi. Tendrias que hacer la conversion a str `DATAFRAME[COLUMNA].astype(str)` para emplear dicha solucion.

Comment: perdona que te moleste tanto, estoy aprendiendo. Agregue la linea de codigo para convertirlo y no funciono. Luego utilice esto, funciono al agregar la columna nueva, pero no me separo los 7str
df2["Ultimos 7"] = df2["NUMERO"].astype(str[-7:])

Comment: Debes convertir la columna NUMERO a `str` no la Ultimos 7.

Comment: Te deje la actualizacion en la respuesta!

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!! ahora si!

Comment: Saludos @Afortiz